Unable to retrieve session data in Django
class DynamicPublicationView(APIView):
    def post(self,request):
        
        serializer = DynamicPublicSerializer(data=request.data)
        print('---------------------------')
        
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()


            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            data=serializer.data
            if 'store' not in request.session:
                request.session['store']={}
            request.session['store']=serializer.data
            
            request.session.modified=True
            print("saved session")
            print(request.session['store'])
            return Response(request.session['store'])

        return Response('form saved in sessions',status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    def get(self,request):
        formdata = request.session.get('store')
        print(formdata)
        return Response(formdata)

when i am hitting get from react server i am unable to retrive the saved data before i saved in post method which is not serializer invalid condition what is the solution
i tried to print in the post method its working but in the get method session state is printing None
